# Why the jersey can't work use jar but maven can?

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I use the jersey first in maven. In maven it look like this:
pom.xml:

```
<!-- jersey -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and it can run the jersey server.but when I change to use the jar way. It doesn't work!

the jars list:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktUpX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I fix it by myself. because after the project compile, the jars doesn't put in the target lib. So I put all the jars in the lib,it can work!